# React: trying to get react-router to work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi All I am trying to figure out how react router works. I have succesfully been able to give a unique route path an id when the link is clicked. it is succesfully showing in the url params. However when I click on the link it just stays on the same page. I want it to go to the  page and display info according to the ID. Can anyone help?

CardRecipe.js

```
const CardRecipe = ({ image, title, calories }) => {
  console.log(calories);
  return (
    <div className="cardRecipeWrapper">
      <Card>
        <CardActionArea>
          <CardContent>
            <CardMedia className="imS" image={image} title={title} />
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
              <img src={image} />
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h5"> Title: {title} </Typography>
            <Typography>
              <strong>Description:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
              consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed odio tortor, accumsan vel
              ullamcorper in, finibus sit amet tortor. Aenean ullamcorper justo
              erat, id venenatis eros porta eu. Aliquam nec nibh nisi. Nunc a
              justo molestie, euismod ante vel, cursus mauris. Nulla rhoncus
              ante tellus, eleifend laoreet magna ultricies ut. Nulla eu dui
              fermentum
            </Typography>
            <Router>
              <Link to={"/Recipe/" + calories}>
                **Link should go to recipedetails new page**
              </Link>
              <Route path="recipe/:id">
                <RecipeDetails />
              </Route>
            </Router>

          </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
```

RecipeDetails.js

```
 import React from "react";
    import { withRouter } from "react-router";
    const RecipeDetails = () => {
      return <div>Hello</div>;
    };
    
    export default withRouter(RecipeDetails);
```

Comment: can you share your code in codesandbox with your routing configuration?

Comment: Sure, here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-darkness-59k3f

Comment: your problem resolved and optimized, can check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved.

Replace files with below:
index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./App";
import RecipeDetails from "./components/RecipeCard/RecipeDetails";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route exact path="/details/:id" component={RecipeDetails} />
    </Router>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import CardRecipe from "./components/RecipeCard/CardRecipe";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
const App = () => {
  const [recipeList, setRecipeList] = useState([]);
  const apiKey = `dd8eec26fed4deab6e4bf0fb409965d2`;
  const appId = `af783d30`;
  const url = ` https://api.edamam.com/search?app_id=${appId}&app_key=${apiKey}&q=chicken`;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const data = await res.json();
        setRecipeList(data.hits);
        console.log(res);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Weekly Menu</h1>
      <Grid container>
        {recipeList.map((recipe) => (
          <Grid item key={recipe.recipe.label} xs={12} md={6} lg={4}>
            <Box m={2}>
              <CardRecipe
                key={recipe.recipe.calories}
                title={recipe.recipe.label}
                calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
                image={recipe.recipe.image}
              />
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

CardRecipe.js

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import "./CardRecipe.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    marginLeft: 2
  },
  root2: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
    margin: "auto"
  }
});
const CardRecipe = ({ image, title, calories }) => {
  console.log(calories);
  return (
    <div className="cardRecipeWrapper">
      <Card>
        <CardActionArea>
          <CardContent>
            <CardMedia className="imS" image={image} title={title} />
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
              <img src={image} alt={`img${calories}`}/>
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h5"> Title: {title} </Typography>
            <Typography>
              <strong>Description:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
              consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed odio tortor, accumsan vel
              ullamcorper in, finibus sit amet tortor. Aenean ullamcorper justo
              erat, id venenatis eros porta eu. Aliquam nec nibh nisi. Nunc a
              justo molestie, euismod ante vel, cursus mauris. Nulla rhoncus
              ante tellus, eleifend laoreet magna ultricies ut. Nulla eu dui
              fermentum
            </Typography>
              <Link to={`/details/${calories}`}>
                Link should go to recipedetails new page
              </Link>

            {/* <Button onClick={()=> history.push('/App.js')}>View more</Button> */}
          </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardRecipe;
```

And if you want to pass values to a navigated component, this how you can achieve that

Parameters with Link

```
    <Link
      to={{
        pathname: `/details/${calories}`,
        state: { image, title, calories }
      }}>
      The link should go to recipe details new page
    </Link>
```

and access like this

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
const RecipeDetails = () => {
  const { state: {image, title, calories} } = useLocation();
  console.log(image, title, calories);
  return <div>Hello: {title}</div>;
};
```

Complete demo [Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-darkness-0w0wi?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks! How would I be able to pass the correct api data down to the card details component?

Comment: @tjStack I have given example below to post. If code is helpful for you please accept/vote for this. Happy coding!